# creating a recursive method in C# for

Tags: recursion

Recursieve methode die voor een gegeven beginsaldo en een gegeven spaarpercentsge uitrekent hoeveel het eindsaldo is na een gegeven aantal jaren.
Must: beginsaldo, spaarpercentage en aantal jaren moet kunnen worden meegeeven aan methode als argumenten’.
Einsaldo teruggeven als returnwaarde
Spaarpercentage in %’
Methode is static en recursief
Methode maakt geen gebruik van static variabelen

---

### English Version

Recursive method that calculates for a given opening balance and a given savings percentage how much the final balance is after a given number of years. Must: initial balance, savings percentage and number of years must be able to be credited to method as arguments'. Return net balance as return value% Savings percentage in% Method is static and recursive Method does not use static variables

Comment: Please post your question in **English**.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static float NettEnd(float NettStart, float percentage, int years)
    {
        if (years == 0)
            return NettStart;
        else
        {
            years = years - 1;
            float factor = 1 + (percentage / 100);
            return NettEnd(NettStart * factor, percentage, years);
        }
    }
```

I used google translate and I believe this is what u are looking for ;). I did test it before sharing!!

Comment: You really shouldn't do the entire problem for someone. Good effort, but OP should show some effort and not expect the internet to solve the problem for him